# Django - wrap child blocks with loop in template

Tags: django, templates, loops

I'm fairly new to Django, and though I know you can't have multiple blocks with the same name in one template (without some hacking), I'm looking for a way to do the following:

```
#parent template
{% for item in block %}
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
      {% block item %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}


#child template
{% extends "parent_template" %}
{% block item %}
  <p>Foo Goes Here</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block item %}
  <p>Bar Goes Here</p>
{% endblock %}
```

And so on, where the result would look something like:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Foo Goes Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Bar Goes Here</p>
    </div>
</div> ... etc ...
```

It doesn't have to be 'specifically' like the above, but that's the general idea.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have solved the problem by now, but in case somebody else needs to do the same thing, I believe the easiest (and possibly only) way is to extract the parts you need into a separate template and include it in a loop. 
For instance, in your case I'd do something like:

```
# collection.html
{% for item in block %}
     {% include "item.html" with element=item %}
{% endfor %}
# item.html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
   {{element}}
   </div>
</div>
```

The major drawbacks here are performance (which may or may not be a problem) and the fact that you might have to extend two different templates when you need to change the inner bits, because you have to change whatever gets included by collection. Of course, you can take care of this by using a variable to decide what item.html template you want to include, like:

```
{% include item_template with element=item %}
```